# Django auto increment fields

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have 2 columns named Serial and Bag I need them to be auto incremented but based on each other and also based on the user that will update the record, so every bag should have 100 serial and reset the number automatically after reaching 100, then start again with Bag number 2 and put 100 serial in it and reset.

For example:

when user update the first record the Bag will start with number 1 and Serial will be also number 1 the second record Bag will still number 1 and the serial will be changed to number 2 till reach 100 Serial in one Bag, then we will start again with bag number 2 and serial number 1 etc ...

Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example? I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: You mentioned "*and also based on the user*". Where would the user be relevant in the incrementing process? Or did you simply mean "*and when the user updates the record*"?

Comment: Yes I mean when user update the first record the Bag will start with number 1 and Serial will be also number 1 the second record Bag will still number 1 and the serial will be changed to number 2 till reach 100 Serial in one Bag, then we will start again with bag number 2 and serial number 1 etc ...

Comment: @IslamFahmy Are you sure the incrementing process happens during update? Or does it happen **when the record is created** since you mentioned *first record* and *second record*.

Comment: the record is already existing but it has empty serial and bag and some more other empty  fields when the user update the other fields so the serial and bag should be updated automatically as mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you explain your example is a bit confusing but I'll try to give you an answer.

I assume the "*2 columns named Serial and Bag*" are fields of the same model and as you replied in the comments "*the record is already existing but it has empty serial and bag*", which means the auto-increment begins when the record is updated. Lastly, you mentioned first and second records implying that there are multiple records in this model. Based on these criteria, what you can do is add a save method in your model:

```py
# Sample model
class Record(models.Model):
  bag = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
  serial = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Ensures the record will only auto-increment during update
    if self.created_at:
      # Retrieves the object with the highest bag & serial value
      latest_record = Record.objects.all().order_by('bag', 'serial').last()

      # Incrementing logic
      if latest_record.serial_no + 1 <= 100:
        self.bag = latest_record.bag if latest_record.bag > 0 else 1
        self.serial = latest_record.serial + 1
      else:
        self.bag = latest_record.bag + 1
        self.serial = 1

    super(Record, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, each time you write save like:

```
record = Record()
record.save()
```

The model save method executes.

Comment: This will potentially lead to a race condition if you have multiple workers/requests etc modifying these Records at the same time. One will fetch a `latest_record`, but another could have updated the database before the first finishes, and now it has a stale value for hte new bags/serial. DB Constraints (`unique_together  = (('bag', 'serial'),)`) might help if you retry when they fail, but it's probably not hte right solution.

Comment: Appreciated dear many thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do the incrementing logic in python, where it is subject to race conditions if multiple updates can happen concurrently, it should be possible to push it down into the database.

Something like:

```sql
update foop set
  bag=vala,
  ser=valb 
from (
    select 
       case when ser >= 5 then bag+1 else bag end as vala,
       case when ser >= 5 then 1 else ser+1 end as valb 
    from foop
    order by bag desc nulls last,
       ser desc nulls last
    limit 1) as tt
where some_primarykey = %;
```

It *might* be possible to translate that into django ORM, but it might also be easier and more readable to just drop into raw SQL or sneak it in via `.extra()` on a queryset than attempt to shoehorn it in.